# How to add class to button in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-button

I've been tasked with converting an Aura component into a LWC. It went well except that I can't seem to add a custom class to the `lightning-button` for styling.

When I look in the rendered code, I noticed that Aura components make a `button` with the custom class, while LWCs make a "lightning-button" element with my class and has a button inside it (which is probably what's causing it to miss using the styling from my CSS class)

This will be used in the community and our person in charge of that won't accept me simply changing my CSS to match. Is there any way to add the class directly to the button element?

Answer (score 0):

Components are inherently "closed" by design. This means that, from another component's perspective, the contents of the first are a black box. In general, this means that you can't target elements inside a component. However, for standard components, you can use [Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_custom_properties) to apply changes to a standard set of features, such as font colors, backgrounds, and more.

Comment: Normally this would be great, but our communities person wants to be able to edit just this one button without editing the entire community. How does one do that?

Comment: @Scarrien You can set a custom class on that one lightning-button, and then set the variable just within that scope: `lightning-button.specialClass { --slds-c-button-font-color: #whatever; }` (this is more illustrative than prescriptive, you may need to play with it a bit).